# Theano import Error-windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, 64-bit, python-import, theano

I have a problem in importing theano in python. When I import Theano in the python 27 32 bit, in Windows 7 64 bit, I get the following errors and warning:
I also should add that currently I have installed GCC 4.8.1.
What I have to do in order to fix it.

Thanks,
Afshin

```
WARNING (theano.gof.cmodule): OPTIMIZATION WARNING: Theano was not able to find the g++ parameters that tune the compilation to your  specific CPU. This can slow down the execution of Theano functions. Please submit the following lines to Theano's mailing list so that we can fix this problem:
 ['# 1 ""\n', 'Reading specs from \\cygnus\\cygwin-b20\\H-i586-cygwin32\\lib\\gcc-lib\\i586-cygwin32\\egcs-2.91.57\\specs\n', 'gcc version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release)\n', ' \\cygnus\\cygwin-b20\\H-i586-cygwin32\\lib\\gcc-lib\\i586-cygwin32\\egcs-2.91.57\\cpp.exe -lang-c -v -undef -D__GNUC__=2 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=91 -Di386 -D_WIN32 -DWINNT -D_X86_=1 -D__STDC__=1 -D__stdcall=__attribute__((__stdcall__)) -D__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__)) -D__declspec(x)=__attribute__((x)) -D__i386__ -D_WIN32 -D__WINNT__ -D_X86_=1 -D__STDC__=1 -D__stdcall=__attribute__((__stdcall__)) -D__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__)) -D__declspec(x)=__attribute__((x)) -D__i386 -D__WINNT -Asystem(winnt) -Acpu(i386) -Amachine(i386) -remap -Acpu(i386) -Amachine(i386) -Di386 -D__i386 -D__i386__ -Di586 -Dpentium -D__i586 -D__i586__ -D__pentium -D__pentium__ -D__CYGWIN32__ -D__CYGWIN__ -\n', 'GNU CPP version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release) (80386, BSD syntax)\n', '#include "..." search starts here:\n', '#include <...> search starts here:\n', ' \\cygnus\\cygwin-b20\\H-i586-cygwin32\\lib\\gcc-lib\\i586-cygwin32\\egcs-2.91.57\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\include\n', ' \\cygnus\\cygwin-b20\\H-i586-cygwin32\\lib\\gcc-lib\\i586-cygwin32\\egcs-2.91.57\\..\\..\\..\\..\\i586-cygwin32\\include\n', ' \\cygnus\\cygwin-b20\\H-i586-cygwin32\\lib\\gcc-lib\\i586-cygwin32\\egcs-2.91.57\\include\n', 'End of search list.\n']
===============================
00001   #include <Python.h>
00002   #include "structmember.h"
00003   #include <sys/time.h>
00004   
00005   // Old Python compatibility from here:
00006   // http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/
00007   #if PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x02050000 && !defined(PY_SSIZE_T_MIN)
00008   typedef int Py_ssize_t;
00009   #define PY_SSIZE_T_MAX INT_MAX
00010   #define PY_SSIZE_T_MIN INT_MIN
00011   // This one was taken from:
00012   // http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h
00013   #define PyNumber_AsSsize_t(ob, exc) PyInt_AsLong(ob)
00014   #endif
00015   
00016   #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
00017   #include "numpy/npy_3kcompat.h"
00018   #define PyCObject_AsVoidPtr  NpyCapsule_AsVoidPtr
00019   #define PyCObject_GetDesc  NpyCapsule_GetDesc
00020   #define PyCObject_Check NpyCapsule_Check
00021   #endif
00022   
00023   #ifndef Py_TYPE
00024   #define Py_TYPE(obj) obj->ob_type
00025   #endif
00026   
00027   /**
00028   
00029   TODO: 
00030   - Check max supported depth of recursion
00031   - CLazyLinker should add context information to errors caught during evaluation. Say what node we were on, add the traceback attached to the node.
00032   - Clear containers of fully-useed intermediate results if allow_gc is 1
00033   - Add timers for profiling
00034   - Add support for profiling space used.
00035   
00036   
00037     */
00038   static double pytime(const struct timeval * tv)
00039   {
00040     struct timeval t;
00041     if (!tv)
00042       {
00043         tv = &t;
00044         gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
00045       }
00046     return (double) tv->tv_sec + (double) tv->tv_usec / 1000000.0;
00047   }
00048   
00049   /**
00050     Helper routine to convert a PyList of integers to a c array of integers.
00051     */
00052   static int unpack_list_of_ssize_t(PyObject * pylist, Py_ssize_t **dst, Py_ssize_t *len,
00053                                     const char* kwname)
00054   {
00055     Py_ssize_t buflen, *buf;
00056     if (!PyList_Check(pylist))
00057       {
00058         PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "%s must be list", kwname);
00059         return -1;
00060       }
00061     assert (NULL == *dst);
00062     *len = buflen = PyList_Size(pylist);
00063     *dst = buf = (Py_ssize_t*)calloc(buflen, sizeof(Py_ssize_t));
00064     assert(buf);
00065     for (int ii = 0; ii < buflen; ++ii)
00066       {
00067         PyObject * el_i = PyList_GetItem(pylist, ii);
00068         Py_ssize_t n_i = PyNumber_AsSsize_t(el_i, PyExc_IndexError);
00069         if (PyErr_Occurred())
00070           {
00071             free(buf);
00072             *dst = NULL;
00073             return -1;
00074           }
00075         buf[ii] = n_i;
00076       }
00077     return 0;
00078   }
00079   
00080   /**
00081   
00082     CLazyLinker
00083   
00084   
00085     */
00086   typedef struct {
00087       PyObject_HEAD
00088       /* Type-specific fields go here. */
00089       PyObject * nodes; // the python list of nodes
00090       PyObject * thunks; // python list of thunks
00091       PyObject * pre_call_clear; //list of cells to clear on call.
00092       int allow_gc;
00093       Py_ssize_t n_applies;
00094       int n_vars;    // number of variables in the graph
00095       int * var_computed; // 1 or 0 for every variable
00096       PyObject ** var_computed_cells;
00097       PyObject ** var_value_cells;
00098       Py_ssize_t **dependencies; // list of vars dependencies for GC
00099       Py_ssize_t *n_dependencies;
00100   
00101       Py_ssize_t n_output_vars;
00102       Py_ssize_t * output_vars; // variables that *must* be evaluated by call
00103   
00104       int * is_lazy; // 1 or 0 for every thunk
00105   
00106       Py_ssize_t * var_owner; // nodes[[var_owner[var_idx]]] is var[var_idx]->owner
00107       int * var_has_owner; //  1 or 0
00108   
00109       Py_ssize_t * node_n_inputs;
00110       Py_ssize_t * node_n_outputs;
00111       Py_ssize_t ** node_inputs;
00112       Py_ssize_t ** node_outputs;
00113       Py_ssize_t * node_inputs_outputs_base; // node_inputs and node_outputs point into this
00114       Py_ssize_t * node_n_prereqs;
00115       Py_ssize_t ** node_prereqs;
00116   
00117       Py_ssize_t * update_storage; // input cells to update with the last outputs in output_vars
00118       Py_ssize_t n_updates;
00119   
00120       void ** thunk_cptr_fn;
00121       void ** thunk_cptr_data;
00122       PyObject * call_times;
00123       PyObject * call_counts;
00124       int do_timing;
00125       int need_update_inputs;
00126       int position_of_error; // -1 for no error, otw the index into `thunks` that failed.
00127   } CLazyLinker;
00128   
00129   
00130   static void
00131   CLazyLinker_dealloc(PyObject* _self)
00132   {
00133     CLazyLinker* self = (CLazyLinker *) _self;
00134     free(self->thunk_cptr_fn);
00135     free(self->thunk_cptr_data);
00136   
00137     free(self->is_lazy);
00138   
00139     free(self->update_storage);
00140   
00141     if (self->node_n_prereqs)
00142       {
00143         for (int i = 0; i < self->n_applies; ++i)
00144           {
00145             free(self->node_prereqs[i]);
00146           }
00147       }
00148     free(self->node_n_prereqs);
00149     free(self->node_prereqs);
00150     free(self->node_inputs_outputs_base);
00151     free(self->node_n_inputs);
00152     free(self->node_n_outputs);
00153     free(self->node_inputs);
00154     free(self->node_outputs);
00155   
00156     if (self->dependencies)
00157       {
00158         for (int i = 0; i < self->n_vars; ++i)
00159           {
00160             free(self->dependencies[i]);
00161           }
00162         free(self->dependencies);
00163         free(self->n_dependencies);
00164       }
00165   
00166     free(self->var_owner);
00167     free(self->var_has_owner);
00168     free(self->var_computed);
00169     if (self->var_computed_cells)
00170       {
00171         for (int i = 0; i < self->n_vars; ++i)
00172           {
00173             Py_DECREF(self->var_computed_cells[i]);
00174             Py_DECREF(self->var_value_cells[i]);
00175           }
00176       }
00177     free(self->var_computed_cells);


......
(I just removed some codes, because Stachoverflow does not allow more than 30000 character......
......

01052   #endif
01053   #if defined(NPY_PY3K)
01054   #define RETVAL m
01055   PyMODINIT_FUNC
01056   PyInit_lazylinker_ext(void) {
01057   #else
01058   #define RETVAL
01059   PyMODINIT_FUNC
01060   initlazylinker_ext(void) 
01061   {
01062   #endif
01063       PyObject* m;
01064   
01065       lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
01066       if (PyType_Ready(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType) < 0)
01067           return RETVAL;
01068   #if defined(NPY_PY3K)
01069       m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
01070   #else
01071       m = Py_InitModule3("lazylinker_ext", lazylinker_ext_methods,
01072                          "Example module that creates an extension type.");
01073   #endif
01074       Py_INCREF(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType);
01075       PyModule_AddObject(m, "CLazyLinker", (PyObject *)&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType);
01076   
01077       return RETVAL;
01078   }
01079   
01080   
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\g++.exe -shared -g -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m32 -IC:\python2732\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32.egg\numpy\core\include -IC:\python2732\include -o C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_30_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.8-32\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_30_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.8-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -LC:\python2732\libs -LC:\python2732 -lpython27
===============================
g++.exe: unrecognized option `-shared'
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_30_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.8-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:0: malformed option `-D  NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION'
In file included from C:\python2732\include\Python.h:8,
                 from C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_30_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.8-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:
C:\python2732\include\pyconfig.h:269: warning: #warning "Please use an up-to-date version of gcc! (>2.91 recommended)"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Pyton\Home Work 1\test-theano\test-theano.py", line 6, in <module>
    from theano import *
  File "C:\python2732\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from theano.compile import \
  File "C:\python2732\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "C:\python2732\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 18, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "C:\python2732\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\python2732\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\vm.py", line 568, in <module>
    import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\python2732\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 116, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\python2732\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2010, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): g++.exe: unrecognized option `-shared'. C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_30_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.8-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:0: malformed option `-D  NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION'. In file included from C:\python2732\include\Python.h:8,.                  from C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_30_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.8-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\python2732\include\pyconfig.h:269: warning: #warning "Please use an up-to-date version of gcc! (>2.91 recommended)".
```

Comment: What g++ version do you have installed in cygwin?

Comment: @ChrisK,
It is 4.8.1

Comment: It is solved. I had a root in windows path that was related to an old version.

Comment: StackOverflow encourages people to answer their own questions if they solve their own problem, to benefit future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your windows path and make sure they are all right.