# Theano crashing on import python3.4

Tags: python-3.x, theano

I've installed Theano 0.8.2 on my windows 10 laptop as per the documentation on their website for python3.4 users. The install of the dependencies and the theano package itself was successful, and all of them are up to date via pip. When I try to import theano however it produces a **very large** error I am unfamiliar with. Prefacing the error is just over 1000 lines of what appears to be code that is printed to the terminal.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018923/theano-import-error-windows-7) seems highly relevant, but I don't understand the answer and the stacktrace does look different from mine. It says the problem is with the compiler, but honestly I have no idea how to resolve it. Does anybody have a solution for me?

This is the stacktrace, minus the code prefacing it.

```
=============================== In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG
                              ^ C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:65:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'
         PY_UINT64_T k0;
         ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:71:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:65:21: error: 'k0' does not name a type
         PY_UINT64_T k0;
                     ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG
                              ^ C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:66:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'
         PY_UINT64_T k1;
         ^ C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: redeclaration of 'unsigned int <anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::__int64'  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG
                              ^ C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:66:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'
         PY_UINT64_T k1;
         ^ C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: note: previous declaration 'unsigned int <anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::__int64'  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG
                              ^ C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:65:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'
         PY_UINT64_T k0;
         ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:71:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:66:21: error: 'k1' does not name a type
         PY_UINT64_T k1;
                     ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' was not declared in this scope  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:88:44: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyLong_FromLongLong(PY_LONG_LONG);
                                            ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:50:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\include/pyport.h:771:34: note: in definition of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'  #       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) RTYPE
                                  ^ C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:90:12: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  PyAPI_FUNC(PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsLongLong(PyObject
*);
            ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:78:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:91:35: error: expected initializer before 'PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong'  PyAPI_FUNC(unsigned PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(PyObject *);
                                   ^ C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:92:35: error: expected initializer before 'PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLongMask'  PyAPI_FUNC(unsigned PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLongMask(PyObject *);
                                   ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:50:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\include/pyport.h:771:34: note: in definition of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'  #       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) RTYPE
                                  ^ C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:93:12: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  PyAPI_FUNC(PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsLongLongAndOverflow(PyObject *, int *);
            ^ In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1: C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64
                       ^ C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:281:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'  typedef PY_LONG_LONG npy_longlong;
         ^ In file included from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:282:31: error: expected initializer before 'npy_ulonglong' 01005       0,        /* tp_base */  typedef unsigned PY_LONG_LONG npy_ulonglong; 01006     0,                         /* tp_dict */
                               ^ 01007      0,                         /* tp_descr_get */ In file included from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0, 01008       0,                         /* tp_descr_set */ 01009     0,   /* tp_dictoffset */
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7: 01010      (initproc)CLazyLinker_init,/* tp_init */ 01011      0,        /* tp_alloc */ C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:583:17: error: 'npy_longlong' does not name a type 01012       CLazyLinker_new,  /* tp_new */
         typedef npy_longlong npy_int64; 01013  };
                 ^ 01014     01015  static PyObject * get_version(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args) C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:584:17: error: 'npy_ulonglong' does not name a type 01016    {
         typedef npy_ulonglong npy_uint64; 01017      PyObject *result = PyFloat_FromDouble(0.21);
                 ^ 01018      return result; 01019  } C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1062:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type 01020   typedef npy_int64 npy_timedelta; 01021    static PyMethodDef lazylinker_ext_methods[] = {
         ^ 01022      {"get_version",  get_version, METH_VARARGS, "Get extension version."}, 01023    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel
*/ 01024    }; 01025     01026  #if defined(NPY_PY3K) C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1063:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type 01027 static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {  typedef npy_int64 npy_datetime; 01028        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
         ^ 01029            "lazylinker_ext", In file included from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:0, 01030          NULL, 01031         -1,
                 from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:23, 01032           lazylinker_ext_methods, 01033           NULL,
                 from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7: 01034          NULL, 01035         NULL, C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:731:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type 01036            NULL
         npy_int64 year; 01037  };
         ^ 01038    #endif 01039    #if defined(NPY_PY3K) 01040 #define RETVAL m 01041  PyMODINIT_FUNC 01042    PyInit_lazylinker_ext(void) { 01043 #else 01044 #define RETVAL 01045    PyMODINIT_FUNC 01046    initlazylinker_ext(void)  01047 { 01048 #endif 01049        PyObject* m; C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:737:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type 01050 
         npy_int64 day; 01051       lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
         ^ 01052        if (PyType_Ready(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType) < 0) In file included from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:0: 01053         return RETVAL; 01054    #if defined(NPY_PY3K) C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h: In function 'FILE* npy_PyFile_Dup2(PyObject*, char*, off_t*)': 01055     m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef); 01056    #else C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:228:32: error: 'PyLong_AsLongLong' was not declared in this scope 01057     m
= Py_InitModule3("lazylinker_ext", lazylinker_ext_methods,
     pos = PyLong_AsLongLong(ret); 01058                           "Example module that creates an extension type.");
                                ^ 01059 #endif 01060        Py_INCREF(&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType); C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h: In function 'int npy_PyFile_DupClose2(PyObject*, FILE*, off_t)': 01061       PyModule_AddObject(m, "CLazyLinker", (PyObject
*)&lazylinker_ext_CLazyLinkerType); 01062    C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:266:41: error: 'lseek' was not declared in this scope 01063      return RETVAL;
     if (npy_lseek(fd, orig_pos, SEEK_SET) == -1) { 01064   }
                                         ^ 01065    

Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below: C:\cygwin64\bin\g++.exe -shared -g -march=haswell -mmmx -mno-3dnow
-msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mmovbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mabm -mno-lwp -mfma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mbmi -mbmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mavx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mlzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=4096 -mtune=haswell
-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m32 -IC:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\gof -o C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp
-LC:\Python34\libs -LC:\Python34 -lpython34 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError() ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 91, in <module>
    raise ImportError() ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 22, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 12, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 638, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 126, in <module>
    preargs=args)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2204, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. '))) Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,.                  from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .                   ^. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG .           ^. C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:65:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'.          PY_UINT64_T k0; .          ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:71:0,.                  from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:65:21: error: 'k0' does not name a type.  PY_UINT64_T k0; .                      ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,.                  from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .                   ^. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG .           ^. C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:66:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'.          PY_UINT64_T k1; .          ^. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: redeclaration of 'unsigned int <anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::__int64'.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .                        ^. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG .           ^. C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:66:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'.          PY_UINT64_T k1; .          ^. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: note: previous declaration 'unsigned int <anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::__int64'.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .                        ^. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:413:30: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  #define PY_UINT64_T unsigned PY_LONG_LONG .           ^. C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:65:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_UINT64_T'.          PY_UINT64_T k0; .          ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:71:0,.                  from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyhash.h:66:21: error: 'k1' does not name a type.  PY_UINT64_T k1; .                      ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,.                  from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' was not declared in this scope.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .               ^. C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:88:44: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyLong_FromLongLong(PY_LONG_LONG); .                                   ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:50:0,.           from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .                        ^. C:\Python34\include/pyport.h:771:34: note: in definition of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'.  #       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) RTYPE .                ^. C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:90:12: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  PyAPI_FUNC(PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsLongLong(PyObject
*); .             ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:78:0,.                  from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:91:35: error: expected initializer before 'PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong'.  PyAPI_FUNC(unsigned PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(PyObject *); .                               ^. C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:92:35: error: expected initializer before 'PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLongMask'.  PyAPI_FUNC(unsigned PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLongMask(PyObject *); .             ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:50:0,.           from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .                        ^. C:\Python34\include/pyport.h:771:34: note: in definition of macro 'PyAPI_FUNC'.  #       define PyAPI_FUNC(RTYPE) RTYPE .                ^. C:\Python34\include/longobject.h:93:12: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  PyAPI_FUNC(PY_LONG_LONG) PyLong_AsLongLongAndOverflow(PyObject *, int *); .             ^. In file included from C:\Python34\include/Python.h:8:0,.                  from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:. C:\Python34\include/pyconfig.h:301:23: error: '__int64' does not name a type.  # define PY_LONG_LONG __int64 .                        ^. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:281:9: note: in expansion of macro 'PY_LONG_LONG'.  typedef PY_LONG_LONG npy_longlong;.          ^. In file included from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0,. from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:282:31: error: expected initializer before 'npy_ulonglong'.  typedef unsigned PY_LONG_LONG npy_ulonglong;.                                ^. In file included from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:22:0,. from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:583:17: error: 'npy_longlong' does not name a type.          typedef npy_longlong npy_int64;.                  ^. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:584:17: error: 'npy_ulonglong' does not name a type.          typedef npy_ulonglong npy_uint64;.                  ^. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1062:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.  typedef npy_int64 npy_timedelta;.          ^. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_common.h:1063:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.  typedef npy_int64 npy_datetime;.          ^. In file included from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:0,. from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:23,. from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:731:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.          npy_int64 year;.     ^. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:737:9: error: 'npy_int64' does not name a type.          npy_int64 day;.      ^. In file included from C:\Users\billy\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_69_Stepping_1_GenuineIntel-3.4.3-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:7:0:. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h: In function 'FILE* npy_PyFile_Dup2(PyObject*, char*, off_t*)':. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:228:32: error: 'PyLong_AsLongLong' was not declared in this scope.      pos = PyLong_AsLongLong(ret);.                                 ^. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h: In function 'int npy_PyFile_DupClose2(PyObject*, FILE*, off_t)':. C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:266:41: error: 'lseek' was not declared in this scope.      if (npy_lseek(fd, orig_pos, SEEK_SET) == -1) {.                                          ^.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is a bit about installing Theano on windows, i will tell you how i SUGGEST for you to do it.

First, remove any other python environment if possible.
Be sure there is no other conflicting environment path of python, just in case.

**1.Install EPD CANOPY**

**2.Install the MinGW package that is on package installer available on Canopy application**

That should be easy to do, you just open the package manager from inside the Canopy application.

**3.Install Theano from inside EPD**

**Before** you go spamming the "pip install",below, :

**pip install --upgrade  --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git**

in every prompt of command you see, **DONT DO IT**.

--
**Instead, Open Canopy.**

In Canopy screen, go to **"Tools"**, and then **open "Canopy Command Prompt"**

A screen exactly like the CMD from windows will open.

On that screen, **execute** :

**pip install --upgrade  --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git**

Should work fine now.

--

However, dont forget you will need , obviously the Windows SDK , depending on the windows version of course.
You can try installing the last Visual Studio with comes with everything you need.

If you need more info on this, check this related Stackoverflow topic :

[Installing theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630020/installing-theano/37780769#37780769)